# "Что сможешь" - запятые с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Требуется ли выделять с двух строн запятыми "что сможешь"?

Папа, я не нашёл на рынке этот набор инструментов. Постарайся разузнать о них(,) что сможешь(,) у своих коллег.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые нужны:

*Папа, я не нашёл на рынке этот набор инструментов. Постарайся разузнАть о них, // **что сможешь**, // у своих коллег.*

1. Это **местоименно-определительное** придаточное  в интерпозиции.

Почему не **цельное** по смыслу выражение?  В этой теме нужно учитывать **структуру оборота и самого** предложения.

2. Сравнить: *УзнАй о них **что можно** (= все возможное) // у своих коллЕг.*

Это **упрощенное** предложение, в которое можно **вписать** похожий по смыслу оборот. Другими словами, оборот не должен быть **распространенным**.

В данном случае у нас структура и интонация простого предложения, а оборот находится в позиции **одного слова**.